Compose - Auto Resizable Span Text
I want to implement a component that consists of different text styles (span) and it auto resize all texts when the text overflows (within it's defined width).
I already have a component that append different text with different styles to each other
data class SpannableTextData(
val text: String,
val style: SpanStyle,
)
@Composable
fun SpannedText(
    textData: List<SpannableTextData>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
) {
    val annotatedString = createAnnotatedString(textData)

    Text(
        modifier = modifier,
        text = annotatedString,
        style = style,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = true,
        maxLines = 1,
    )
}

@Composable
private fun createAnnotatedString(textData: List<SpannableTextData>) =
    buildAnnotatedString {
        textData.forEachIndexed { index, spannableText ->
            if (spannableText.style != null) {
                withStyle(
                    style = spannableText.style,
                ) {
                    append(spannableText.text)
                }
            } else {
                append(spannableText.text)
            }
        }
    }

I also have another component as auto resizable text which automatically resize a text if it overflows.
@Composable
fun AutoReSizeText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    color: Color = SomeColor,
    style: TextStyle = SomeStyle,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = TextAlign.Start,
    multiplierValue: Float = 0.99f,
) {
    var multiplier by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = overflow,
        style = style.copy(
            fontSize = style.fontSize * multiplier
        ),
        color = color,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        onTextLayout = {
            if (it.hasVisualOverflow) {
                multiplier *= multiplierValue
            }
        }
    )
}

I tried combining these two so in a way that when the text hasVisualOverflow if change the font size of all span text sizes equally.
@Composable
fun SpannedAutoResizeText(
    textData: List<SpannableTextData>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textAlign: TextAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
    multiplierValue: Float = 0.99f,
) {
    var multiplier by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val annotatedString = createAnnotatedString(textData, multiplier)

    Text(
        modifier = modifier,
        text = annotatedString,
        onTextLayout = {
            if (it.didOverflowWidth) {
                multiplier *= multiplierValue
            }
        },
        textAlign = textAlign,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
    )
}

@Composable
private fun createAnnotatedString(
    textData: List<SpannableTextData>,
    multiplierValue: Float,
) = buildAnnotatedString {
    textData.forEachIndexed { index, spannableText ->
        if (spannableText.style != null) {
            withStyle(
                style = spannableText.style.copy(fontSize = spannableText.style.fontSize * multiplierValue,
            ) {
                append(spannableText.text)
            }
        } else {
            append(spannableText.text)
        }
    }
}

However it didn't work. My expection was that when didOverflowWidth is triggered, it changes the multipler. Therefore, createAnnotatedString is recomposed and it changes the font size based on multiplier value.
Am I missing something? Is there any better approach?
